# I have an issue while entering in an kibana development mode

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I download the Kibana form the  git "https://github.com/elastic/kibana".
I check my node version is equal to kibana's node version 6.11.5. 
when i run npm start or npm run elasticsearch, i have face an following issue 
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you typed npm install after you cloned the repository ?

Comment: yes,but before that i upgrade my node version same as in .nodeversion in kibana dir and afterthat i change my kibana.yml.but kibana doesnt runs in the root ,i create a user for that

Comment: I little bit confuse, you run version 7.0.0 or 5.6.3?

Comment: I get the kibana source code from this git clone https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git and I set the kibana version to 5.6.3 using git checkout 5.6

Comment: I am looking on your logs and I see that when you run npm run elasticsearch, elastic 7 start to work

Comment: yes elastic 7 starts , during this process i skip that git checkout 5.6.then after i set that git checkout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159654/discussion-between-rajesh-a-and-lax).